# Elements not recognized by get_attribute('class') name

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver

In the following loop, im simply traversing a [page](https://www.facebook.com/ads/library/?active_status=all&ad_type=all&country=ALL&q=hearthstone&sort_data%5Bdirection%5D=desc&sort_data%5Bmode%5D=relevancy_monthly_grouped&search_type=keyword_unordered&media_type=all);
element by element, and stopping to retrieve the URL of a `button type` only.

However my script was stopping on elements not true of the `get_attribute('role') == 'button'` check, which was quite frustrating.

As such I realized the class name for all of the buttons i needed [as best shown here highlighted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cE78m.png), were the same. Which would be insanely convenient to check for, however its not working at all.

What am i doing wrong?

```
if starting_element.get_attribute('role') == "button" and starting_element.get_attribute('class') == "x1i10hfl xjqpnuy xa49m3k xqeqjp1 x2hbi6w x972fbf xcfux6l x1qhh985 xm0m39n x9f619 x1ypdohk xe8uvvx xdj266r x11i5rnm xat24cr x1mh8g0r x2lwn1j xeuugli x16tdsg8 xggy1nq x1ja2u2z x1t137rt x6s0dn4 x1ejq31n xd10rxx x1sy0etr x17r0tee xdl72j9 x1q0g3np x193iq5w x1n2onr6 x1hl2dhg x87ps6o xxymvpz xlh3980 xvmahel x1lku1pv xhk9q7s x1otrzb0 x1i1ezom x1o6z2jb xo1l8bm x108nfp6 xas4zb2 x1y1aw1k xwib8y2 x1swvt13 x1pi30zi x78zum5 x1iyjqo2 xs83m0k":
                button_text = starting_element.text
                if button_text in meta_cta_buttons:
                    parent_element = starting_element.find_element(By.XPATH, "..")
                    while (True):
                        if parent_element.tag_name != 'a':
                            # moves up element ancestry chain 
                            parent_element = parent_element.find_element(By.XPATH, "..") 
                        else:
                            cta_url = parent_element.get_attribute('href')
                            # store links in a set
                            unique_store_urls.add(cta_url)
                            break
                else:
                    continue
            else:
                continue
```

*Can provide more of the outer loop if needed, but it is not relevant to the questions concern.*

Answer (score 0):

Here's a quick way to get the hrefs of the Call-to-Action "Learn More" buttons using [SeleniumBase](https://github.com/seleniumbase/SeleniumBase):

```py
from seleniumbase import BaseCase
BaseCase.main(__name__, __file__)

class MyTestClass(BaseCase):
    def test_base(self):
        self.open("https://www.facebook.com/ads/library/?active_status=all&ad_type=all&country=ALL&q=hearthstone&search_type=keyword_unordered&media_type=all")
        self.wait_for_element_visible('a:contains("Learn More")')
        elements = self.find_elements('a:contains("Learn More")')
        for element in elements:
            print(element.get_dom_attribute("href"))
```

Run with `python` or `pytest`.

Comment: I dont see how this is any different from using `get_attribute` function. Instead just feels more unnecessary

Comment: If ``get_attribute()`` works the same as ``get_dom_attribute()``, use whichever one you prefer.

Comment: Well the problem is, it `should work` but is clearly not given my code. Its allowing elements such as `<div class="_4ik4 _4ik5" style="line-height: 14px; max-height: 28px; -webkit-line-clamp: 2;" xpath="1">Learn More</div>` to be true for the main if statement, which is frustrating. I basically just want to filter anything outside the CTA buttons out :/

Comment: The solution posted gives you the URLs of all the CTA ("Learn More") buttons.